# Procedural stretched materal

Tags: materials

I was experimenting with Blender's material nodes and texture and accidentally created a (in my opinion, beautiful) stretched material by creating a small mesh and applying a large image texture. If it matters, I'm using Blender 2.82a.

How can I procedural generate this material using Cycle's material nodes?

I'm very inexperienced with Blender, so details would be appreciated.

Description of material: cross section of wood stretched along the curve of a mesh

Material samples:

[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stretch any texture using the Mapping Node.

1. Add *Mapping* node right after *Texture Coordinate* node
2. Change type from *Point* to *Texture* (but it will work either way)
3. Crank up the scale disproportionally

[image]